# What is the platform eclipse/flashbuilder/titanium studio are built on

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, titanium

I feel like I should know the answer to this question, but it is obvious that alot of development platforms are built on the same "engine" (eclipse,flashbuilder,titanium studio to name a few).

Simply put, is this "engine"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Platform. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform

(SO wants a longer answer than just the URL)

Comment: I suspected that eclipse was "the base"... Thanks